# enable a model on Django Admin on Dreamhost

Tags: django, dreamhost, django-grappelli

Hi I've created a new app (Paginas) but I cannot see inside the admin page. I've added 'paginas' to INSTALLED_APP. My admin.py is

```
# coding=utf-8
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Pagina

class PaginaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("titulo",)}
    list_display = ('titulo' , 'contenido')

    class Media:
        js = ('/layout/grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js','/layout/grappelli/tinymce_setup/tinymce_setup.js')

admin.site.register(Pagina,PaginaAdmin)
```

I am using passenger_wsgi.py file, I've touched tmp/restart.txt file, I've killed python process

I don't know what else can I do

The project you can see it on github https://github.com/totechess/paralisis_cerebral

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error do you get when you go to your site yoursite.com/admin/
Did you add admin to INSTALLED_APPS? Note the S

```
....
'django.contrib.admin',
....
```

Perhaps your urls.py are not updated properly? What is the error?

Comment: I don't have any error on admin page, I've updated the project on github